# Extending a <select> list programmatically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

With a bootstrap project I have the following code to build an area where I can display a set of options,  which are selectable for further actions. Like this:

```
<!--   List of entries -->
<select id="jobsList"  class="form-control" size="10">
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>def</option>
    <option>xyz</option>
</select>
```

For that `<option>` list I need to extend it programmatically but can't find the correct coding. With selecting a 'line on the list' (one of the options) I can get it's position but any attempt to add/insert/etc will always fail with TypeError, like this:

```
$('#jobsList')[0].selectedOptions[0].before("<option>123</option>")
TypeError: $(...)[0].selectedOptions[0].before is not a function
```

Maybe I could read all of the `<option>` statements, insert my new one and write it back to the `<select>`.

But there should be another way, but which?

*Note: Using Firefox 37*

Comment: When you were typing your question, there was big orange **How to Format** box next to the text area with formatting tips. Worth a read. The toolbar at the top of the text area also has all sorts of formatting aids, and a **[?]** button. I've fixed the markup in the question.

Comment: Thanks for that hint .. indeed, having some problems with formatting on stackoverflow .. hope to be better .. soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with T.J.Crowder's answer, but didn't found a solution to place the additional option at a given place. There was another answer with another thread which finally helped:

Doesn't place at given place (jobNo)

    `$("#jobsList")[0].options.add(new Option(cJob, jobNo));`

The following codes is OK.

    `var x = document.getElementById("jobsList");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = cJob;
    var sel = x.options[x.selectedIndex];
    x.add(option, jobNo);`

Think there is a jQ solution also !?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to add an option to the list, you want `options`, not `selectedOptions`, and you want `add` not `before`:

```
$("#jobsList")[0].options.add(new Option("text", "value"));
```

*(The second argument is optional. Well, the first probably is too, but you don't want a blank option.)*

Example:

```js
var list = $("#jobsList")[0];
var n;
for (n = 1; n < 4; ++n) {
  list.options.add(new Option("Option " + n, n));
}
```

```html
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<select id="jobsList" class="form-control"></select>
</form>
```

Comment: Half way the solution ;)
I need to *insert* the new option at a given place.
That goes also for my next question: how to sort or just upshift a given option in the selection?